US Tax-exempt filing form
I thought as a US nonprofit I could file Form 990-EZ.
When I was applying for an EIN, I selected corporation as my nonprofit's structure. I believe 501c(3) nonprofits must be structured as a corporation or association.
However, my EIN letter is saying I must file US 1120. Which one should I file though?
Form 1120 Instructions
On Page 2 of the above PDF, under Who Must File it says:

Unless exempt under section 501, all domestic corporations (including corporations in bankruptcy) must file an income tax return whether or not they have taxable income. Domestic corporations must file Form 1120, unless they are required, or elect to file a special return. See Special Returns for Certain Organizations, later.

Under the aforementioned, Special Returns for Certain Organizations, it says tax exempt organizations can file 990-T, which is not 990-EZ but it seems similar.

Attached a screenshot of the SS-4 I received saying I must file 1120


An entity classified as a non-profit for tax purposes files an annual IRS form 990 and not an IRS form 1120.
But, to be classified as a non-profit for tax purposes, you need to do more than fill out an IRS form SS-4 to get an EIN. And, the correct box on IRS Form SS-4, line 9a to that you must fill out for a non-profit that is not a church is "Other non-profit", rather than "corporation" even if it is organized as a non-profit corporation. The word "corporation" on form SS-4, Line 9a actually means "for profit corporation."

In addition to the SS-4 to get a non-profit tax classification, you also need to fill out another form:

To apply for recognition by the IRS of exempt status under IRC Section
501(c)(3), you must use either Form 1023 or Form 1023-EZ.

From the IRS website.

Yes, you're right - I see it now on the instructions for SS-4: "Unless you are a church, or church-controlled organization, if you are a corporation that is a nonprofit entity, check the “other nonprofit organization" box, and specify the purpose." I guess I will have to send a letter to the IRS to correct the form.
